How do we measure the "holes" (zeros) of the set of $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combinations of $f_i : G \to G$ where $G$ is an abelian group?
Question:
Let $G$ be a normed abelian group.  Namely the triangle inequality holds $|g + h|\leq |g| + |h|$.  An example would be $G = \Bbb{Z}$ together with $|\cdot| =$ absolute value.
Now suppose that you have a finite set of functions $f_i : G\to G, i = 1..n$, which are typically not group homomorphisms in applications.  Now take the space of $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combinations of the $f_i$, $X = \{ \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j f_j : \lambda_j \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.  This forms an abelian subgroup of simply the set of all functions $\{f: G \to G\}$ under pointwise $+$.

Can we use group theory and / or topology to compute $$h = \min\{ |x| : 0 \neq x \in G; \forall f \in X,f(x) = 0\}$$?
If not, then would the Number-theoretic Transform tell us anything (especially because we can assume periodicity; see below)?
And if not to that, then
does this seem like a problem that Group Cohomology could address?

Close upper bounds will work as well for my application, which is to prime numbers.
Random thought: is there some sort of Zariski topology for abelian groups that has to do with general functions and not only polynomials?
More Information:
Take $G = \Bbb{Z}$ and let the $f_i : G \to G$ be $f_i(x) = \delta_0(x \mod i), i=1..n$, so that the $f_i$ are essentially Dirac combs.  Then $h = p_{\pi(n) + 1} = \text{ a prime number}$.  With certain choice of $f_i$ the above formulation will also apply to $2k$-separated prime numbers ($k=1$ is twin primes), in which case $h$ will be the least $2k$-separated prime average that is greater than $n$, for example.  Because of this formulation's generality, of course it easily applies to other open questions in NT.
Thus, for these prime gap problems, the $f_i$ are all periodic with readily determined periods.  So, you can add that on as a hypothesis in the above question.

You surely need some requirement on the $f$. Allowing totally arbitrary functions means $h$ does not even exist, the set in question would be empty; given any $x$ I'd be allowed to make a function $f$, $f(x)\neq 0$. Assuming $G$ has more than one element... maybe you want the $f$ to be order preserving?

@FShrike yes we probably do, but could then just append "If it exists" to the definition of $h$.  The functions I'm working with would be the Dirac combs as described.

@FShrike another way to put it would be $h = \infty$, as in all the positions are filled by some function, and there are no holes other than perhaps $0$.

huh${}{}{}{}{}$

@FShrike Now that you've slept, have any new ideas come to mind on this approach?  I think there's data in signal analysis about a Dirac comb + a delayed Dirac comb, and this causes an "interference pattern" - somewhere on Wikipedia I read this about a week ago.  Anyhow, for prime gap problems, those Dirac comb + shifted Dirac comb are exactly what is required.

I don't think I have anything to contribute toward this problem

@FShrike my latest look was at the "linear algebra" of it.

Bump.  Just wondering if any Signal Processing experts have anything to say about this, because of the presence of the Dirac comb.
